# Docker Postfix Admin bulk aliases, custom maps, and custom config files

Tags: postfix, configuration, migration, docker-compose, aliases

I'm in the process migrating my bare metal postfix implementation over to docker to essentially upgrade my old box to a more docker/vm-centric server and hopefully add virtual domain support. I'm temporarily using an unused laptop for this process.

I've got like a billion and one aliases on my bare metal box. Is there a way to bulk add aliases so I don't have to put these in piecemeal? I can't seem to find a good way to do this (other than maybe just hack the database but hoping there's a more elegant way via the webui).

Likewise, I've got some highly customized master.cf, main.cf, sasl_passwd and header_check rules that must be in place before I change over the smtp server.

Is there a way to port all of this in via the webui or do I need to do this locally in the docker container's datastore?